# Let $f$ be a real-valued function with finite derivative in a form interval $(a, + ∞)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

Let $f$ be a real-valued function with finite derivative in a form interval $(a, + ∞)$.

If $f '(x) → 1$ when $x → + ∞$, prove that $f (x) / x → 1$ when $x → + ∞$

I have tried to prove that using the mean value theorem but I have not been able to get the answer ...

Answer (score 1):

For every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $x>N$ implies $|f'(x)-1|<c$.

Let $y>x>N$, MVT implies that $f(y)-f(x)=f'(u_y)(y-x), u_y\in [x,y]$, this implies that ${{f(y)}\over y}=f'(u_y)-f'(u_y){x\over y}$. We deduce that $lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}{{f(y)}\over y}= lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}f'(u_y)$, and $|lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}{{f(y)}\over y}-1|=lim_{y\rightarrow +\infty}|f(u_y)-1|<c$ for every $c>0$, this implies that $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{{f(y)}\over y}=1$.